# How to generate power BI report dynamically (By passing parameters to reporting API) without building data model

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-datasource

I did not find a way to generate reports by executing SQL queries directly on database in power BI.
I am new to this tool and surprised that we dont have such capability in it.

I have a reporting requirement where I need to generate reports on the fly (Without predefining model in powerBI) by executing direct queries against database.

I am dealaing with 1 TB data to import it in powerBI is not feasible so I want to execute queries on source database itself rather than building model and in powerBI.

Do we have any API level interface to generate reports programatically in powerBI? I did not find much help on this topic.

is it possible in power BI to generate reports by directly executing queries against database without replicationg / importing data to powerBI.

Also is it possible to generate report programatically by passing parameters in report arguments.

e.g.

https://powerbi-report-url/reportid&param1=value1 etc.

Please suggest if any workaround is there for this requirement.

Comment: `Do we have any API level interface to generate reports programatically in powerBI?` - no unfortunately. [Relevant suggestion](https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas/suggestions/7345565-power-bi-designer-api), response: "We’ll consider it for the future along with other suggestions and plans. Thanks!"

Comment: Can you please suggest workaround to process large data in powerbi without creating data model.

Comment: You can use custom sql queries for import by using `Get data` -> `Sql server` -> `Advanced options` -> `Sql statement`

Comment: Alternatively you could use [DirectQuery](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-desktop-use-directquery/?cdn=disable)

Comment: yes but again direct queries will load entire data (in TB's) in powerbi right which does not seems to be feasible option.

Comment: You didn't check the link ;) 
`DirectQuery – no data is imported or copied into Power BI Desktop` ... `DirectQuery lets you build visualizations over very large datasets, where it otherwise would be unfeasible to first import all of the data with pre-aggregation`

Comment: Thanks My bad I skipped that part.

Comment: http://docs.powerbi.apiary.io/#reference/datasets/datasets-collection I found API documentation for the same. Yes it does not support parameterization but we can create datasource dynamically,

Comment: I am trying to execute Curl url to get PowerBI reports data. I have copied Curl URL from Firebug (By selecting criteria it creates POST request.). I am trying to execute same request using REST client. I am getting below response. Can you please suggest Status code 5 what does it mean?  

"results": [
        {
            "jobId": "e8c0c1dd-06f0-4cf4-881c-8745446dbfaf",
            "result": {
                "error": {
                    "statusCode": 5
                }
            }
        }
    ]

Comment: You should post that as a separate question